# Transaction logs with large data processing in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, inno-setup, laravel-5.1

Don't know if I posted in the correct site. But here goes, Im having a problem with database transaction in processing large files. What my program do is I upload a csv file and in that file it can have up to 50,000 records. Right now it worked when I processed 200 rows but when I tried with 20,000 rows it never get to insert in my db (i saw the insertion sql in my logs but when i check it out it never entered). So I'm guessing that my buffer size for the transaction logs hit its limit.

I have this code in my laravel

```
try {
  DB::beginTransaction();
  process my logic (validation, log, etc..)
  DB::commit()
}catch() {
  log::error();
  DB::rollback;
}
```

I just added these two config in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[innodb]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
innodb_log_file_size    = 64M
```

I thought it would fix my problem but sadly not. Please help.

Comment: Why aren't you using load data in file?

Comment: thought of it but i'm changing the value of the other fields when processed before inserting it into my tables.

Comment: Still load data in file is the right way to go. Your PHP code should process your CSV and then output another CSV which you can use with LOAD DATA. It can handle 50k lines in seconds.